# xterm.js initial height and scroll bar problems

Tags: javascript, html, css, xtermjs

I am using `xterm` javascript control, and it is not sizing/resizing properly. I have the following HTML, creating two panes via `div`, left pane for `xterm` and right pane for a future side bar.

```
  <div id="panes" class="panes">
    <div id="terminal-pane" class="terminal-pane"></div>
    <div id="sidebar-pane" class="sidebar-pane"></div>
  </div>
```

With styles

```
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }

    div.panes {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
    }

    div.terminal-pane {
      width: 70%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    div.sidebar-pane {
      width: 30%;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

The `xterm` is created with

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/xterm/css/xterm.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/xterm/lib/xterm.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/xterm-addon-fit/lib/xterm-addon-fit.js"></script>

  <script>
    var fitAddon = new FitAddon.FitAddon();
    var term = new Terminal();
    term.loadAddon(fitAddon);
    term.open(document.getElementById('terminal'));
    fitAddon.fit();
  </script>
```

At `term.open`, when I place a breakpoint, I see the initial width is sized to the pane width, but the height of the terminal is 25 lines fixed. I expected the height to be sized to the pane height.

Issue 1: can I do something to make `term.open` create the terminal initially full height?

Next, after `fitAddon.fit`, the terminal is resized to an integral of the character dimensions. The width might shrink a few pixels if it is not an even multiple of characters, and the height similarly stretches down all the way, minus any pixels that another row will not fit into.

Issue 2: can the `term.open` create the terminal on integrals of character width/height, or can I calculate and adjust the `div` before calling `term.open`?

Issue 3: the `fitAddon.fit` isn't positioning the scroll bar properly. The terminal is on top of it and the left side of the scroll bar can get covered. Is there a way to fix this?

Finally, I add this:

```
  <script>
    function onSize() {
      if (fitAddon !== undefined) {
        fitAddon.fit();
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', onSize, false);
  </script>
```

I should see `fitAddon.fit` resize the terminal when the browser is resized.

Issue 4: If the width changes but the row count does not, then the scroll bar does not move. When sizing bigger, the terminal will cover it, and when sizing smaller, the scroll bar will be clipped. When sizing to its initial position, part or all of the scroll bar shows up. However, if the terminal contains enough lines to scroll, then the scroll bar will move with resize.

What should I be doing differently?

Comment: issue1: `term.open` does no size calcs at all, it just attaches the DOM to the already existing term instance for IO, so the terminal now knows, where to output things and how to grab user input. In terms of terminal size `term.open` is passive.
To get such a behavior, call the terminal ctor with other col/row values than 80x25.

issue2: Again `term.open` does no size calcs. Ofc you can precalc the correct size prehand yourself, maybe have a look at the AddonFit code. For most cases it is easier to start with defaults (80x25) and do an early resize with the help of the addon.